# Port forwarding with docker for wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker

I'm a newbie to docker. I followed the tutorials here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pe6a8Jbvi9E to create a WordPress site with docker. He is explaining about port forwarding with the following command,

```
docker run --link=my_mysql:mysql -p 80:80 -d wordpress
```

As of my understanding, this will redirect all the requests in the port 80 of host to the port 80 of container. But how this will communicate with the port 3306 of mysql? And also in that tutorial database details not set anywhere for wordpress , than from where the db config values are taken from? Can someone explain? Sorry if this are very basic questions.

Answer (score 3):

> But how this will communicate with the port 3306 of mysql?

The `wordpress` container will communicate with the `mysql` container, because that is what a link allows: (see [Linking Containers Together](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/))

> Links allow containers to discover each other and securely transfer information about one container to another container. When you set up a link, you create a conduit between a source container and a recipient container.

So the port 3306 is *not* exposed to the host (like the 80 port is), but it is visible to `wordpress` container.

> Docker creates a secure tunnel between the containers that doesn't need to expose any ports externally on the container; you'll note when we started the db container we did not use either the `-P` or `-p` flags.
>   That's a big benefit of linking: we don't need to expose the source container, here the `mysql` database, to the network.
>
> Docker **defines a set of environment variables for each port exposed by the source container**.
>   Each variable has a unique prefix in the form:

```
<name>_PORT_<port>_<protocol>
```

> The components in this prefix are:
>
> - the alias `<name>` specified in the `--link` parameter (for example, mysql)
> - the `<port>` number exposed
> - a `<protocol>` which is either TCP or UDP